# How to start clients from server itself in python?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm developting a automation framework with little manual intervention.
There is one server and 3 client machines.

what server does is it sends some command to each client one by one and get the output of that command and stores in a file.

But to establish the connection I have to manually start clients in different machine in the command line, is there a way that the server itself sends a signal or something to start the client sends command stores output and then start next client so on in python?

Edited.
After the below suggestion, I used spur module

```
 import spur
 ss = spur.SshShell(hostname = "172.16.6.58",username ='username',password='some_password',shell_type=spur.ssh.ShellTypes.minimal,missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept)
 res = ss.run(['python','clientsock.py'])
```

I'm trying to start the clientsock.py file in one of the client machine (server is already running in the current machine) but, it hangs there nothing happens. what am i missing here?

Comment: For this to work, the server would first have to negotiate a connection to the client machine - but how would it do that if the client software isn't already on and listening for server connections already? :)

Comment: Run servers and clients and all machines. Not full-blown apache installations - SSH, netcat or something similar would do.

Comment: Hi @ jDo how would we do it with ssh?

Comment: This sounds like a job for [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/).

Comment: Why build this yourself? Lots of tools exist for distributing tasks in python, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236508/distributed-python-programming

Comment: @sanyesh paramiko for SSH as @Robᵩ suggested, an actual job distribution framework as @Dave Bacher suggested or a simple TCP connection like `netcat -lk 12345` (server) client: `netcat localhost 12345` (client) and some bash to parse if all you're sending is "STOP" and "GO". The right choice depends on your specific requirements, the amount of data, the number of processes, etc. etc.

Comment: Hi all, Could you please look at the edited part of the question and let me know what is going wrong?